# Shortkeys with win key is not working when use remote desktop

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have a question about windows remote desktop, that's it.
When I use remote desktop, I cannot use any shotkeys with Win key in the remote window, for example : win+D win+E. When I press win key, it should open the start menu, but nothing happened.

My client is windows 8.1, the remote machine is windows server 2008 r2.

Have you met this problem? What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your remote desktop in full screen mode?

When you launch mstsc.exe, click on 'Show Options', and go to 'Launch Resources' tab. This should have an option under 'Keyboard' section -> 'Apply Windows key combinations:'. It should be 'Only when using the full screen'. if you want to use Win+ combination of keys only on your remote computer, then you can select the option 'Only the remote computer'.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,

Silvia Doomra

Comment: Yes, my remote desktop is in full screen mode. I just try you suggestion, it doesn't works. I try connect that remote computer via other computer, it still doesn't works. So I suspect the remote computer has a problem. Thanks.

Comment: no, your remote computer does not have a _problem_. we have the same _problem_ too. The Windows key is accessing the local computer, not on the remote. 
yes, we have set **Apply windows key to remote..* - that was the first thing we did and the first thing most people do ^^ Especially those who use SO.

No its not a driver problem and no I will not reinstall my windows :)

Comment: I would love to have alt+tab working on remote while windows+tab on my local machine, any idea how you got there?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. Close all RDP Clients on remote machine
2. Close all RDP Clients on local machine
3. Try again